# Autolayout UITabBar items in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to implement a simple mobile browser in iOS. I am trying to include two UIToolbars; one at the top and one at the bottom. The top toolbar will consist of a UITextField and a GO button. The bottom toolbar will consist of back and forward buttons.

I want this to work correctly in both portrait and landscape modes. However, I noticed that autolayout does not work for UIToolbar items. So I cannot set constraints for my UITextField and the buttons. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes autolayout does not work for UIToolbar items because they are mostly `UIBarItem` instead of subclass of `UIView`.

You can still set up constraints by using special items [image: img]